# Cannot reset lock screen password

Tags: lock-screens, password, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand and I forgot my lock screen password. I set a full 16-character password but now I forgot the password.

Somehow I unlocked the screenlock, but now I can't reset it to a simple one. I'm typing and typing the same password that got me in but no use. I don't want to reset the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's not an issue with the password being correct, I'm wondering if there is a chance you set encryption on the device.

On my Samsung, that forces the password to be an actual password, as opposed to a PIN or swipe. In order to change the type of screen lock away from the high security password, you need to first decrypt the phone. It should then let you select the screen lock of your choice. Worth a shot to look!

Answer (score 0):

the maximum character limit that the phone can remember for a password is 16 characters, but for some reason it can actually be longer. Try typing in only the first 16 characters, this should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access or twrp go to /data/system
Delete the following

```
gatekeeper.password.key

gatekeeper.pattern.key

locksettings.db

locksettings.db-shm

locksettings.db-wal
```

It will remove your lockscreen what ever it is
how ever if your device have fingerprint and you have set it
It will require your fingerprint to set a new lockscreen